# Docker isn't fowarding port to redis

Tags: docker, port-forwarding, redis, docker-networking

I'm trying to run redis in a docker container on AmazonLinux, and I can't for the life of me get it to forward the port. It starts as it should and appears to be working, but there is no process listening on 6379 on the host box, as one would expect. What should I do?

Here is `uname -a`:

```
Linux <host name omitted>.internal 5.4.176-91.338.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP <start time omitted> x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `docker run -p6379:6379 redis`:

```
1:C 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.018 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.018 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.018 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
1:M 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.019 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.020 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.020 # Server initialized
1:M 01 Apr 2022 06:09:18.020 * Ready to accept connections
```

Logs from `sudo dockerd -D` daemon:

```
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.711242117Z] Calling HEAD /_ping
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.712201263Z] Calling POST /v1.40/containers/create
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.712439060Z] form data: {"AttachStderr":true,"AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":true,"Cmd":null,"Domainname":"","Entrypoint":null,"Env":[],"ExposedPorts":{"6379/tcp":{}},"HostConfig":{"AutoRemove":false,"Binds":null,"BlkioDeviceReadBps":null,"BlkioDeviceReadIOps":null,"BlkioDeviceWriteBps":null,"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps":null,"BlkioWeight":0,"BlkioWeightDevice":[],"CapAdd":null,"CapDrop":null,"Capabilities":null,"Cgroup":"","CgroupParent":"","ConsoleSize":[0,0],"ContainerIDFile":"","CpuCount":0,"CpuPercent":0,"CpuPeriod":0,"CpuQuota":0,"CpuRealtimePeriod":0,"CpuRealtimeRuntime":0,"CpuShares":0,"CpusetCpus":"","CpusetMems":"","DeviceCgroupRules":null,"DeviceRequests":null,"Devices":[],"Dns":[],"DnsOptions":[],"DnsSearch":[],"ExtraHosts":null,"GroupAdd":null,"IOMaximumBandwidth":0,"IOMaximumIOps":0,"IpcMode":"","Isolation":"","KernelMemory":0,"KernelMemoryTCP":0,"Links":null,"LogConfig":{"Config":{},"Type":""},"MaskedPaths":null,"Memory":0,"MemoryReservation":0,"MemorySwap":0,"MemorySwappiness":-1,"NanoCpus":0,"NetworkMode":"default","OomKillDisable":false,"OomScoreAdj":0,"PidMode":"","PidsLimit":0,"PortBindings":{"6379/tcp":[{"HostIp":"","HostPort":"6379"}]},"Privileged":false,"PublishAllPorts":false,"ReadonlyPaths":null,"ReadonlyRootfs":false,"RestartPolicy":{"MaximumRetryCount":0,"Name":"no"},"SecurityOpt":null,"ShmSize":0,"UTSMode":"","Ulimits":null,"UsernsMode":"","VolumeDriver":"","VolumesFrom":null},"Hostname":"","Image":"redis","Labels":{},"NetworkingConfig":{"EndpointsConfig":{}},"OnBuild":null,"OpenStdin":false,"StdinOnce":false,"Tty":false,"User":"","Volumes":{},"WorkingDir":""}
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.726732730Z] container mounted via layerStore: &{/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a/merged 0x5590d6c33c40 0x5590d6c33c40}
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.726817190Z] Probing all drivers for volume with name: 6e4cc5e5d43a1e7d3ca4144de24bd9c00733a78083fbba4fe2245a75b3d56440
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.727783987Z] Registering new volume reference: driver "local", name "6e4cc5e5d43a1e7d3ca4144de24bd9c00733a78083fbba4fe2245a75b3d56440"
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.729422536Z] copying image data from b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d:/data, to 6e4cc5e5d43a1e7d3ca4144de24bd9c00733a78083fbba4fe2245a75b3d56440
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.738464370Z] Calling POST /v1.40/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/attach?stderr=1&stdout=1&stream=1
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.738575127Z] attach: stdout: begin
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.738611364Z] attach: stderr: begin
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.738904225Z] Calling POST /v1.40/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/wait?condition=next-exit
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.739341603Z] Calling POST /v1.40/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/start
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.740139082Z] container mounted via layerStore: &{/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a/merged 0x5590d6c33c40 0x5590d6c33c40}
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.744258295Z] bundle dir created                            bundle=/var/run/docker/containerd/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d module=libcontainerd namespace=moby root=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a/merged
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:17.988922333Z] event                                         module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/create
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:18.001833824Z] event                                         module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/start
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:47.990640595Z] Calling HEAD /_ping
DEBU[2022-04-01T06:09:47.991013563Z] Calling GET /v1.40/containers/json?all=1
```

Even after starting, output of `sudo netstat -tulpn` looks like:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4541/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4323/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39297         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      52578/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41327         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      52531/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3532/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39635         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      52568/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40853         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4158/containerd     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4541/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::50051                :::*                    LISTEN      52556/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      3532/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 :::30001                :::*                    LISTEN      52543/docker-proxy  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           4047/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           3532/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           3656/chronyd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:677             0.0.0.0:*                           3532/rpcbind        
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                3532/rpcbind        
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                3656/chronyd        
udp6       0      0 fe80::10cc:ecff:fe9:546 :::*                                4084/dhclient       
udp6       0      0 :::677                  :::*                                3532/rpcbind
```

Result of `docker image inspect redis`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:f1b6973564e91aecb808142499829a15798fdc783a30de902bb0c4133fee19ad",
        "RepoTags": [
            "redis:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "redis@sha256:0d9c9aed1eb385336db0bc9b976b6b49774aee3d2b9c2788a0d0d9e239986cb3"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2022-01-26T22:42:40.969131359Z",
        "Container": "2552e57869499f961c051f933f396e9a108a328aa50f0527e7b709c8453e2e5d",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "2552e5786949",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "6379/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "REDIS_VERSION=6.2.6",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.2.6.tar.gz",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA=5b2b8b7a50111ef395bf1c1d5be11e6e167ac018125055daa8b5c2317ae131ab"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"redis-server\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:53fbfdd5f8b83eec2c846e7c3f88a4b796ec25ea6c5d6732c3bafaa7e2e8e14a",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.7",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "6379/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "REDIS_VERSION=6.2.6",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.2.6.tar.gz",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA=5b2b8b7a50111ef395bf1c1d5be11e6e167ac018125055daa8b5c2317ae131ab"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "redis-server"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:53fbfdd5f8b83eec2c846e7c3f88a4b796ec25ea6c5d6732c3bafaa7e2e8e14a",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 112712915,
        "VirtualSize": 112712915,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a12ee374312449d74fca6ef38a854445bf841c53ef4947ebff3cb75361072d68/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/547ac2f21a71cf3db5354bc1b09edf86115f6432e098de29ee4adf223d10911c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b76e0751542d640e474043902100b31b6b5bd681027999cadc72b63530eebc6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/817c7b0fc802642a6ca3bfce75ebbfa7967e72d40701d7cf97d284adabd88ffd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f75bc8a98ce6ef6ed4c3aa49cf02085a6ed54136daf2ff0bbb4b6305b1c236e/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb8ae711a8095ef1c6947d7cdfb5bac9212bebb27a49cac37927eb9d50e6c6e6/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb8ae711a8095ef1c6947d7cdfb5bac9212bebb27a49cac37927eb9d50e6c6e6/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb8ae711a8095ef1c6947d7cdfb5bac9212bebb27a49cac37927eb9d50e6c6e6/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:7d0ebbe3f5d26c1b5ec4d5dbb6fe3205d7061f9735080b0162d550530328abd6",
                "sha256:92b6c42121d80f330a80c20afa928e19c31ab3a5fe7cf9c91517fa8cc468b33f",
                "sha256:65845b69eb5c3291dd610ddf2f61f524ab206f9754900d9f3512fcbc2d38604f",
                "sha256:7048818d16571a765e2b0cf82c20d627abebccec73ac3d7b7973501000e6e05d",
                "sha256:c61d5cbf862134aad34822e96d9efc009cca19ad604419cb3f8cf8857eb18372",
                "sha256:ff503dae4eb68eb7a71095e5b1b1b123f42d37e923222038b64fba5a80b13307"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Output of `docker ps -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS               NAMES
b169b17dd219        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   31 seconds ago      Up 29 seconds                                         practical_driscoll
0564d11aeae4        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   33 minutes ago      Exited (0) About a minute ago                         recursing_clarke
900b852ec798        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago      Exited (0) 33 minutes ago                             charming_wright
44d5f3956d9e        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 minutes ago      Exited (0) 34 minutes ago                             tender_ellis
a75ff92a9e6a        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 minutes ago      Exited (0) 39 minutes ago                             amazing_allen
0d18733b003f        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   41 minutes ago      Exited (0) 41 minutes ago                             clever_shaw
f97c93ca0d51        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 minutes ago      Exited (0) 41 minutes ago                             silly_tereshkova
b10d05112f4e        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 minutes ago      Exited (0) 42 minutes ago                             elegant_cartwright
4200e4305f99        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   46 minutes ago      Exited (0) About a minute ago                         lucid_meitner
6701dc80f692        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago      Exited (0) 46 minutes ago                             hungry_leakey
dab5c8ac4dba        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago      Exited (0) 48 minutes ago                             optimistic_mcnulty
01cbbe59cb4a        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) 50 minutes ago                             agitated_wilson
f8061cc7f8d3        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          happy_grothendieck
dadda17513ec        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          focused_ardinghelli
998a9daf5262        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          romantic_banach
05739cc6d02c        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          dazzling_dhawan
68985a25899a        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          clever_euler
be975ad41a79        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          goofy_wescoff
9fd9712c5fc8        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          keen_curie
37d7c4cf2926        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          cranky_fermat
ccf184edccf4        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                          friendly_tereshkova
b884651bcf3b        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   35 hours ago        Exited (0) About an hour ago                          brave_swanson
af4c2654b9bf        kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (137) 2 minutes ago                            quickstart-armada-server-worker
a6fc51a4c718        kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (137) 2 minutes ago                            quickstart-armada-server-control-plane
d2c3e07142fd        redis                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (255) 4 weeks ago                              angry_napier
dc66ce3ed03b        kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (137) About a minute ago                       quickstart-armada-executor-1-control-plane
b1898eb8ebc3        kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (137) 2 minutes ago                            quickstart-armada-executor-1-worker
c49aad627c97        kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (137) 2 minutes ago                            quickstart-armada-executor-0-control-plane
273ee5313543        kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Exited (137) 2 minutes ago                            quickstart-armada-executor-0-worker
```

Output of `docker inspect practical_driscoll`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d",
        "Created": "2022-04-01T06:09:17.714237408Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "redis-server"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 295188,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-04-01T06:09:18.001996349Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:f1b6973564e91aecb808142499829a15798fdc783a30de902bb0c4133fee19ad",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d/b169b17dd219e1833add0244a3780900810a2c43c4f2be63e68d04c3e6163f4d-json.log",
        "Name": "/practical_driscoll",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {
                    "max-file": "10",
                    "max-size": "10m"
                }
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "6379/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "6379"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
"SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": [
                {
                    "Name": "memlock",
                    "Hard": -1,
                    "Soft": -1
                }
            ],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb8ae711a8095ef1c6947d7cdfb5bac9212bebb27a49cac37927eb9d50e6c6e6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a12ee374312449d74fca6ef38a854445bf841c53ef4947ebff3cb75361072d68/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/547ac2f21a71cf3db5354bc1b09edf86115f6432e098de29ee4adf223d10911c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b76e0751542d640e474043902100b31b6b5bd681027999cadc72b63530eebc6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/817c7b0fc802642a6ca3bfce75ebbfa7967e72d40701d7cf97d284adabd88ffd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f75bc8a98ce6ef6ed4c3aa49cf02085a6ed54136daf2ff0bbb4b6305b1c236e/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e99c57f3e0a991850fabb2b3dae7a66963bee38235d99b4792e24dc018dd0b0a/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "6e4cc5e5d43a1e7d3ca4144de24bd9c00733a78083fbba4fe2245a75b3d56440",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/6e4cc5e5d43a1e7d3ca4144de24bd9c00733a78083fbba4fe2245a75b3d56440/_data",
                "Destination": "/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "b169b17dd219",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "6379/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "REDIS_VERSION=6.2.6",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.2.6.tar.gz",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA=5b2b8b7a50111ef395bf1c1d5be11e6e167ac018125055daa8b5c2317ae131ab"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "redis-server"
            ],
            "Image": "redis",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "NetworkDisabled": true,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "da9cad9507c9374138c65b67b60d1bce45202c09006de923c655f2c26abec96b",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/da9cad9507c9",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: You command is working for me. I noticed that you are not sending the container into the background. Are you doing your checks on a second shell, or did you stop the container before doing your checks?

Comment: Inspecting the image does not provide much useful information. It would be more helpful to see the output of `docker ps -a` and `docker inspect containername`.

Comment: I did not stop the container. `dockerd` , `docker run ...` and commands to inspect like `netstat` and `docker ps` are in separate tty's

Comment: Please see the edits I made to include output of` docker ps -a` and `docker inspect <containername>` as well as updated outputs from other cmds.